# matchMedia flakey in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries

I trying to use window.matchMedia to query the browser and move `div#move_me_around` when the browser screen resizes below a certain threshold. It works great in Chrome, Safari, and only ***sometimes*** in ***Firefox***.

That is what I am trying to figure out. I've test Firefox and it has the `window.matchMedia` object, the`mediaQueryList` object, which itself has the `addListener` method.

Half of the time the event is fired and it works, the other half  it doesn't work at all..

```
# CoffeeScript
$(document).ready ->

mql = window.matchMedia 'screen and (max-width: 600px)'
$move_me_around = ($ "#move_me_around")

mql_handler = (mql) ->
   if mql.matches is true
          $move_me_around
      .appendTo("#sidebar")
       else
      $move_me_around
      .prependTo("#center_column")


mql_handler(mql)

mql.addListener (mql) -> 
   mql_handler(mql)
```

Comment: +1 for a well-explained question!  Welcome to SO!